# Excel dynamic range not including all values in the column

Tags: excel, dynamic, range

I'm trying to use dynamic ranges to create some charts in Excel but I'm finding that it is not including the last 1-4 values in the column.  My data starts in row 7 so this is the formula I am using:

```
=OFFSET('Process Data'!$A$7,0,0,COUNTA('Process Data'!$A:$A)-6,1)
```

For this set of data my last row is 907 but when I select the range to see what cells it is referring to I find that it only refers to as far down as row 897.

Is this normal for dynamic ranges? If not, how can I fix it? I'm finding it's happening with both these large tables of data and with smaller ones of ~5 rows.

Comment: Do you have data in the first 6 rows in column A?

Comment: You can do this with INDEX(): `=$A$7:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("ZZZ",$A:$A))`

Comment: If the data is number and not text in Column A you can use this instead: `=$A$7:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(1E+99,$A:$A))`

Comment: I have a bunch of headings and subheadings in the first 6 rows.

Comment: Remember that counts only counts those cells with values. If you have any blanks it will not count. The index formulas do not care.